# Juju gui problem with login

Tags: juju, maas

Hello i have installed *maas* and *juju*, now that i want to login juju's gui there is 
user and password

user-admin

password

i have tried the password from my environments.yaml but no success. 
I use the ip address of the node to login

> https://'192.168.50.103'/login

, but i can't the address of the maas server is

> 192.168.50.101/MAAS

.
Is the username user-admin wrong? 
Any advices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user-admin` is correct.

It sounds like you are on the right track, and I can't tell exactly how to help you from your description.  My best guess is that you are not extracting the right password from your ~/.juju/environments.yaml file.  Make sure that you are looking at the stanza for your MAAS environment.  If you see a line that says

```
admin-secret: aaaAAAbbbBBB111222333
```

then you should be able to use `aaaAAAbbbBBB111222333` as the password.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. 'a123' was incorrect a123 was correct :)